# What is the most efficient way to find the image type(like jpeg,gif) from a multipart image file in java

Tags: java, image

I am exposing a restful webservice,where i accept the image as multipart data.
My task is to find the image type(like jpeg,gif,etc)
After googling,i could see the below code.

```
ImageInputStream iis = ImageIO.createImageInputStream(o);
Iterator iter = ImageIO.getImageReaders(iis);
if (!iter.hasNext()) {
    return null;
}

ImageReader reader = (ImageReader) iter.next();
iis.close();

return reader.getFormatName();
```

Image IO is being used and also using an **iterator**..
Is there any efficient way or simple method to do my task?

Comment: Iterators are not always performance hits.  It depends heavily on what you are iterating, and how.  Did you benchmark this, or is your "performance hit" just something you think exists?

Comment: Its always good to improve performance.I was asking whether there is any other possible way to do my task..

Comment: Actually, it is not always good to improve performance of a step.  Doing so without some awareness of how your application functions as a whole is called `Premature Optimization` and often can lead to unsatisfactory results.  The most common unsatisfactory result is that you put a lot of effort into making 0.1% of your application performance 50% faster, leading to a net gain of 0.05% in time while 2% of your application is using 50% of the time.  But it can be worse, you can force certain slower big-O performance by demanding you access things a certain way.  Benchmark first, then optimize.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://dzone.com/articles/determining-file-types-java)?

Comment: @Edwin,dude i just want to be simple..;-)

Comment: @Thevenin,need to look into this too..

Comment: @AkhilVSankar If you want it to be simple, benchmark before you start.  Otherwise, how will you know if you actually sped up anything?  The JVM optimizes aggressively these  days, and simple rules like "iterators == slow" are typically both right and wrong depending on circumstance.  But Hey, you just want it to be simple, so you're going to rewrite your code to not use ImageIO's convenience functions.  Think about it.

Comment: @EdwinBuck  "iterators == slow" are typically both right and wrong depending on circumstance.The circumstance is explained clearly in my question..

Comment: @Jill So you have read the code behind ImageIO and have analyzed it, and have noticed that the iterator is clearly slower than another technique?  If not, then the circumstance is most certainly not clear.  Perhaps the iterator is just iterating over table entries, and not the entire image data.  Until you lift the cover, you don't know what is under it.